# No operations allowed after statement closed issue

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, database-connection

I have the next methods in my singleton to execute the JDBC connections

```
public void openDB() throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException,
        InstantiationException, SQLException {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mbpe_peru";//mydb
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "admin");
    st = conn.createStatement();
}

public void sendQuery(String query) throws SQLException {
    st.executeUpdate(query);
}

public void closeDB() throws SQLException {
    st.close();
    conn.close();
}
```

And I'm having a problem in a void where i have to call this twice.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

Main.getInstance().openDB();
Main.getInstance().sendQuery("call insertEntry('"+EntryID()+"','"+SupplierID()+"');");
Main.getInstance().closeDB();

Main.getInstance().openDB();
for(int i=0;i<dataBox.length;i++){
Main.getInstance().sendQuery("call insertCount('"+EntryID()+"','"+SupplierID()+"','"+BoxID()+"');
Main.getInstance().closeDB();
}
}
```

I have already tried to keep the connection open and send the 2 querys and after that closed and it didnt work... The only way it worked was to not use the methods, declare the commands for the connection and use different variables for the connection and the statement. I thought that if i close the Connecion and the Statement I could use the variable once again since is a method but I'm not able to. Is there any way to solve this using my methods for the JDBC connection?

Comment: Do you really need to open and close the database so often? In my JDBC programming, I usually open the database once, execute all my queries, then close it before the program ends.

Comment: No, I did that when i got the error.

Comment: Note that you are missing closing double quotes and brackets in your `sendQuery` invocation.

Comment: You shouldn't have the connection as an instance member. Make it a local variable; have openDB() return it, and pass it as a parameter to the other methods. Also, closeDB() should be called within a finally block.

Comment: Ok I'm going to use the connection as a local variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is

```
   Main.getInstance().openDB();
   for(int i=0;i<dataBox.length;i++){
      Main.getInstance().sendQuery(....);
      Main.getInstance().closeDB();
    }
```

You're closing the database on each iteration. You should e.g. do

```
   Main.getInstance().openDB();
   for(int i=0;i<dataBox.length;i++){
      Main.getInstance().sendQuery(....);
    }
    Main.getInstance().closeDB();
```

Comment: That was the problem thanks. Well another thing too if you check closeDB im closing the connection and if i want to sendQuery again i have to close the statement before

Answer (score 0):

I suggest changing your code as follows:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    Main.getInstance().openDB();
    Main.getInstance().sendQuery("call insertEntry('"+EntryID()+"','"+SupplierID()+"',);

    for(int i=0;i<dataBox.length;i++){
        Main.getInstance().sendQuery("call insertCount('"+EntryID()+"','"+SupplierID()+"','"+BoxID()+"');
    }

    Main.getInstance().closeDB();
}
```

I haven't tested this, so I hope it works.

Comment: There is no line it just appear 'No operations allowed after statement is closed' if i use a System.out.print it only works before the second SendQuery()

Comment: @Washu How are you running your program? Where does the error appear?

Comment: @Washu If you are still having difficulties, please edit your quesiton with an update which includes the exact code you tried and the exact error message it gives.

Answer (score 0):

Create two statements. And better use a parametrised statement with setters.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/mbpe_peru";//mydb
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "admin");

CallableStatement insertEntrySt = conn.prepareCall("CALL insertEntry(?, ?)");
insertEntrySt.setInt(1, EntryID());
insertEntrySt.setInt(2, SupplierID());
insertEntrySt.executeUpdate();
insertEntrySt.close();

CallableStatement insertCountSt = conn.prepareCall("CALL insertCount(?, ?, ?)");
...

conn.close(;
```

Comment: I tried it with that.. had an error in the 1st CallableStatement